# Version number mask validation in jquery or GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, gwt, jquery-validate

I am looking for version number mask plugin. I want to validate version number entered in textbox that should in format of X.Y.Z or XX.YY.ZZ and XYZ should in number.

Please help me if there is any plugin in jquery or GWT to validate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GWT [RegExp](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html) functions.